# pyspark dataframe's collect method raises exception

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have example 10 rows, 9 columns data frame in pandas and want to use it in pyspark.
For some reason pyspark method `collect()` raises error, and error is meaningless or cryptic enough to be seen as meaningless.
My question is why I am not able to use my dataframe in pyspark?
Please find all details below.

python 3.6.5, java 10.0.2
pyspark installed with pip, run on single machine.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
#'0.23.4'
pf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id1': {0: 'id046', 1: 'id041', 2: 'id036', 3: 'id067', 4: 'id047', 5: 'id003', 6: 'id052', 7: 'id024', 8: 'id051', 9: 'id048'}, 'id2': {0: 'id018', 1: 'id047', 2: 'id039', 3: 'id100', 4: 'id086', 5: 'id002', 6: 'id018', 7: 'id062', 8: 'id043', 9: 'id051'}, 'id3': {0: 'id0000006976', 1: 'id0000009477', 2: 'id0000003195', 3: 'id0000001035', 4: 'id0000005874', 5: 'id0000001900', 6: 'id0000002599', 7: 'id0000005962', 8: 'id0000003913', 9: 'id0000001059'}, 'id4': {0: 97, 1: 89, 2: 23, 3: 44, 4: 79, 5: 10, 6: 42, 7: 34, 8: 51, 9: 60}, 'id5': {0: 67, 1: 75, 2: 33, 3: 31, 4: 75, 5: 34, 6: 73, 7: 57, 8: 58, 9: 49}, 'id6': {0: 7103, 1: 699, 2: 7180, 3: 3189, 4: 5530, 5: 4013, 6: 4912, 7: 1677, 8: 9892, 9: 5903}, 'v1': {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 3, 6: 5, 7: 5, 8: 3, 9: 1}, 'v2': {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 5, 8: 5, 9: 4}, 'v3': {0: 2.4358, 1: 15.3333, 2: 82.1465, 3: 32.4652, 4: 2.4358, 5: 73.0214, 6: 13.958, 7: 30.7107, 8: 5.1784, 9: 63.2878}})

import pyspark as ps
ps.__version__
#'2.3.1'
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("appname").getOrCreate()
sf = spark.createDataFrame(pf)
sf.collect()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                           
  File "/home/jan/git/my-project/spark/py-spark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py
spark/sql/dataframe.py", line 466, in collect                                   
    sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()                                     
spark/sql/dataframe.py", line 466, in collect                          [63/4510]    sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()                                     
  File "/home/jan/git/my-project/spark/py-spark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py
4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__                                         answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)                     
  File "/home/jan/git/my-project/spark/py-spark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py
spark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco                                           
    return f(*a, **kw)                                                            File "/home/jan/git/my-project/spark/py-spark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py
4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value                                      format(target_id, ".", name), value)                                   
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o39.collectToPython.                                                                               
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException                                            
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)             
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)             
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)            
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.s
cala:46)                                                           
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodI
nsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)                                           
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodI
nsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)     
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$vis[42/4510]nsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)                                           
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(
TraversableLike.scala:733)                                                              at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(Has
hMap.scala:103)                                                                 
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(Has
hMap.scala:103)                                                                         at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala
:230)                                                                                   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)          at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.s
cala:732)                                                                       
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(Closu
reCleaner.scala:432)                                                            
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)                 
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)                  
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)             
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$C
losureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)                         
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$$
losureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)                [21/4510]        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$C
losureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)                         
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)                      at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCl
eaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)                                          
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)                 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2073)        
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)                at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)                                                                       
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.s
cala:112)                                                                       
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)                    
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)                     
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.sca
la:297)                                                            
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset
.scala:3195)                                                                    
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset
.scala:3192)    
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply[0/4510].scala:3192)                                                                    
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)   
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)                                                               
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3253)          
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3192)     
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                                       
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                                
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                             
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)           
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)         
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)   
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)                               
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) 
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)  
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)               
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: great! it could have been handled more nicely so users who installed default java (for ubuntu 10.0.2 currently) would not waste time on debugging their code...

Comment: Yeah, the exception couldn't be less useful.